# CiviEvent: missing are Total Fees, Payment Method

Tags: civievent, registration, paylater

First screen capture is from test drive. Second screen capture is from live.
Total Fees missing, Payment method missing.
Civi 4.7.8 on Joomla 3.5.1.

[image: Total Fees, Payment method Missing - shows in test drive though]
[image: Total Fees, Payment method Missing when live]

Comment: Please try to take a live copy and deploy to a local server and compare with your test copy - make sure you have all the extension same as test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Administer / Systems Settings / Resource URL's
Change CiviCRM Resource URL from using URL variable to absolute path, i.e. replace [civicrm.root] with the specific path for the site.
** This is a specific issue to Joomla sites only.

Answer (score 2):

Ann - the symptoms you describe here all point to an issue with JavaScript not being loaded properly.

General recipe for trouble shooting this is to check your Browser's console for Error messages: in Firefox - you could do this by installing Firebug plug-in on Chrome you can launch the Developer Tools.

Here's an excellent write-up on troubleshooting JavaScript errors by one of the core team member's: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0

Comment: This is a specific issue to the Joomla platform, JavaScript is not loading properly, which is addressed once you use absolute paths. Once the change is made, like magic, the fields appear and work.